# Mirgrate from apigee edge to apigee x

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apigee

Does anybody has any idea on how to migrate from `apigee edge` to `apigee X`. By that I mean migrating all the proxy, apps, shared-flows, KVMs, Target servers, cache etc.

Comment: For proxies, you can download the latest version from apigee edge and upload them in apigee x. I think same goes for Shared Flows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [Apigee sackmesser tool](https://github.com/apigee/devrel/tree/main/tools/apigee-sackmesser#scenario-export-all-resources-of-a-specific-org)  that can export configuration from Edge or X.

Apigee Sackmesser lets you export an Organization including org and env configs, proxies and shared flows with the export command

```
sackmesser export --apigeeapi -u "$APIGEE_USER" -p "$APIGEE_PASS" -o "$APIGEE_ORG"
```

With the deploy command you can then iterate through the exported proxies or point at a specific config to deploy them to another platform.

However, there are certain limitations as this is not designed to serve as a fully automated migration tool as it lacks migration features like:

1. Migration of encrypted KVM entries (can't be exported).
2. Migration of Keystores (Certs can't be exported).
3. Shared flow(sf) dependency resolution (if sf A uses sf B then sf B needs to be deployed before sf A).
4. Export of specs.

So with the above tool you can migrate Proxies, App keys and a few other data from APIGEE edge to APIGEE x with export and deploy commands.